# How can I filter doc_count value which is a result of a nested aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

How can I filter the doc_count value which is a result of a nested aggregation?
Here is my query:

```
    "aggs": {
            "CDIDs": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "CDID.keyword",
                "size": 1000
              },
              "aggs": {
                "my_filter": {
                  "filter": {
                    "range": {
                      "transactionDate": {
                        "gte": "now-1M/M"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                "in_active": {
                  "bucket_selector": {
                    "buckets_path": {
                      "doc_count": "_count"
                    },
                    "script": "params.doc_count > 4"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
```

The result of the query looks like:

```
      {
          "aggregations" : {
            "CDIDs" : {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count" : 2386,
              "buckets" : [
                {
                  "key" : "1234567",
                  "doc_count" : 5,
                  "my_filter" : {
                    "doc_count" : 4
                  }
                },
                {
                  "key" : "12345",
                  "doc_count" : 5,
                  "my_filter" : {
                    "doc_count" : 5
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

I'm trying to filter the second doc_count value here. Let's say I wanna have docs that are > 4 so the result should be having only one aggregation result in a bucket with doc_count = 5. Can anyone help how can I do this filter? Please let me know if any additional information is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a close look at the [bucket_selector](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) aggregation. You simply need to specify the aggregation name in `buckets_path` section i.e. `"doc_count":`**`"my_filter>_count"`**

Pipeline aggregation *(buckets_path)* has its own syntax where `>` acts as a separator. Refer to this [LINK](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html#buckets-path-syntax) for more information on this.

### Aggregation Query

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{  
      "CDIDs":{  
         "terms":{  
            "field":"CDID.keyword",
            "size":1000
         },
         "aggs":{  
            "my_filter":{  
               "filter":{  
                  "range":{  
                     "transactionDate":{  
                        "gte":"now-1M/M"
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "in_active":{  
               "bucket_selector":{  
                  "buckets_path":{  
                     "doc_count":"my_filter>_count"
                  },
                  "script":"params.doc_count > 4"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nishanth. Welcome to sof!! If you think this has resolved the issue, feel free to accept it. The way you accept is, click on the grey arrow mark next to the answer.  You can refer to this link as reference https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3287 That way users who make use of sof would get to know this query has been resolved and it would also help new users to understand this question has a valid solution. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you Kamal. It worked. I have actually figured that I should use my_filter._count just after posting this(that was just a fluke didn't see any ref). Your solution helped me to know why should I do that and the ref link as well... Thanks a ton...cheers